# QOpenGL error : "Invalid VAO/VBO/pointer usage" "Array object is not active"

Tags: c++, pointers, vbo, vao, qopenglwidget

I'm currently trying to render a skybox using the QOpenGL library of Qt. For that, I tried to modify the QOpenGL "cube" example that is provided by Qt (I'm using the latest Qt 5.13 version).

The vertex and index buffers are initialized in a class called `GeometryEngine`, in which vertex and index array are defined as well. In the example, the vertex array has texture coordinates, so I got rid of those and kept only the position coordinates, because every operation regarding the skybox texture will be done in the shaders.

There's also a function called `initTextures` in the window class that I modified to load the textures of the 6 faces of the cube (I don't know if this part is correct though).

I also set up an OpenGL debug Logger using this example : https://www.trentreed.net/blog/qt5-opengl-part-5-debug-logging/.

When I execute the code, I only get a window with a black screen and nothing rendered and the following error messages : 
`GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Invalid VAO/VBO/pointer usage.` and
`GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Array object is not active.`

Has anynone encountered this issue before and fixed it ? Because I don't think I forgot any part of the rendering process. I only modified the input data and the shaders (but I got no error from that part).

First, I thought the core of the problem was due to the vertex and index array, so I tried to use only a vertex buffer by repeating the vertices for each triangle in the vertex array, but I got the same error messages.

Since I got no compile error, I tried to locate the problem by using the `#if 0 [...] #endif` on each functions until I got no OpenGL error messages. I finally isolated the origin in the `drawCubeGeometry` method in the `GeometryEngine` class, where the position attribute are sent to the shaders and the draw call is issued. there seems to be a problem with the `setAttributeBuffer` and `glDrawElements` calls, but I can't figure it out.

I tried looking for solutions online but there is so little questions asked about QOpenGL.

In GeometryEngine.cpp :

```
void GeometryEngine::initCubeGeometry()
{
    QVector3D vertices[] = {
        // Vertex data for face 0
        QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f),  // v0
        QVector3D( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), // v1
        QVector3D(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f),  // v2
        QVector3D( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), // v3

        // Vertex data for face 1
        QVector3D( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), // v4
        QVector3D( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // v5
        QVector3D( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f),  // v6
        QVector3D( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f), // v7

        // Vertex data for face 2
        QVector3D( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // v8
        QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),  // v9
        QVector3D( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f), // v10
        QVector3D(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f),  // v11

        // Vertex data for face 3
        QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // v12
        QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f),  // v13
        QVector3D(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f), // v14
        QVector3D(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f),  // v15

        // Vertex data for face 4
        QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // v16
        QVector3D( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // v17
        QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), // v18
        QVector3D( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), // v19

        // Vertex data for face 5
        QVector3D(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), // v20
        QVector3D( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), // v21
        QVector3D(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f), // v22
        QVector3D( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f) // v23
    };

    GLushort indices[] = {
         0,  1,  2,  3,  3,     
         4,  4,  5,  6,  7,  7, 
         8,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 
        12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 
        16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 
        20, 20, 21, 22, 23  
    };
    // Transfer vertex data to VBO 0
    arrayBuf.bind();
    arrayBuf.allocate(vertices, 24 * sizeof(QVector3D));

    // Transfer index data to VBO 1
    indexBuf.bind();
    indexBuf.allocate(indices, 34 * sizeof(GLushort));
}

void GeometryEngine::drawCubeGeometry(QOpenGLShaderProgram *program)
{

    // Tell OpenGL which VBOs to use
    arrayBuf.bind();
    indexBuf.bind();

    // Offset for position
    quintptr offset = 0;

    // Tell OpenGL programmable pipeline how to locate vertex position data
    int vertexLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_position");
    program->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
    program->setAttributeBuffer(vertexLocation, GL_FLOAT, offset, 3, sizeof(QVector3D));

    // Draw cube geometry using indices from VBO 1
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 34, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

GLWidget.cpp :

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{

    // Clear color and depth buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    texture->bind();

    // Calculate model view transformation
    QMatrix4x4 matrix;
    matrix.translate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    matrix.rotate(rotation);

    // Set modelview-projection matrix
    program.setUniformValue("mvp_matrix", projection * matrix);

    // Use texture unit 0 which contains cube.png
    program.setUniformValue("texture", 0);

    // Draw cube geometry
    geometries->drawCubeGeometry(&program);
}
```

For now I only try to display a red cube (in the fragment shader) to see if it works. I will focus on applying the texture later.